# When using GLM to fit data, how do we select which family the data belongs to

Tags: r

How does GLM source code analyze data, and when we do not know what kind of data exactly belongs to, how to select the best family to fit and get the best result

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Hope the linked post answers you; if it suggests further questions, please ask them.